# Cannot add App_Code folder to WebSite project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, app-code

Using VS2008, I am trying to add an App_Code folder from add-->folder-->Add ASP_NET folder.

The App_Code folder option is there as expected BUT ... it's disabled!?

I am pretty sure I am working with a WebSite project (and not a Web Application) because I can add all the other ASP_NET folders (App_Data - App_themes etc) and also because I don't have the controls declarations in my-code behind (as opposed to Web Application where you have partial classes with controls declaration and eventHandlers etc.). Fact is, if it's not a website project how come I can add the other ASP_NET folders? And also - why I am not getting any designer file with controls declaration etc? This is the way things used to work in VS2005.

If I go ahead and add App_Code folder myself as a normal folder it picks-up the icon of the ASP_NET App_Code folder - so it seems to be working fine.

Still it's bugging me 'cause I can't understand why the opion is disabled in the first place.

Any clue why this is happening?

**EDIT**: I am trying to create a new **web site** and I get only the **web application** template so I doubt I was able to create a website in the first place. A bit confused here!

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a new folder and calling it App_Code, there's nothing extra special about App_Code than it simply being a folder of that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it is web site project and not web application?

Comment: Wait - I am trying to create a new web site and I get only the web application template so I doubt I was able to create a website in the first place.

Comment: Fact is, if it's not a website project how come I can add the other ASP_NET folders? and also - why I am not getting any designer file with controls declaration etc?

Comment: I established it's a web application!

Answer (score 5):

No idea why it's happening, but you should be able to just add a new folder in the Solution Explorer and rename/call it App_Code.

Do this in Windows Explorer even, if you like.

Refresh and it'll pick it up.

Comment: I did that and it picked it up - but why is it disabled in the first place?

Comment: My first thought was you were debugging. But that appears to disable the whole menu when I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You add a new folder to project. Then, rename it as App_Code. Visual studio could revise the folder as App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you add .cs file, it will be created?

Did this option worked for you before? Did you do something before it stopped working?

Comment: I just installed VS2008 - so it's the first time I try - even if I add .cs files it's still disabled

Answer (score 0):

There's really no such thing as a "web site project".  Web sites are project-less, in that they don't contain a .csproj (or .vbproj) file in the folder.  If you see this file, then it's a "web application" project.  Also, if you're selecting from the menu "new project...", then you're not selecting a "web site".

The only way that you're using a web site, is by selecting "new web site" from the VS File menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get to the `App_Code` new folder option in the New ASP.Net Folder drop down if you are working in a Website and not in a web application. Caught me out a few times too. Hope that this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can't add the App_Code folder to a Web Application because this folder is designed for runtime compilation by asp.net and the Web Application project is designed for you to precompile your website into a dll which you can find in the Bin folder and deploy to your site.

So, for Web App Projects, you should instead Add a folder called something like  'CodeFolder' and then add you class in there. Then right click properties on that class file and set its build config to compile rather than content.